# Find the percentage of a group by count row in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table as

```
Person| Count

A | 10
B | 20
C | 30
```

I use code as below to get above table:

```
select new_table.person, count(new_table.person)
from (person_table_1
inner join person_table_2
on person_table_1.user_name = person_table_2.user_all_name) new_table
group by new_table.person
```

However, I wish to have the percentage for each row based on overall sum in count.

Expected:

```
Person| Count | Percentage

A | 10 | 0.167
B | 20 | 0.333
C | 30 | 0.500
```

I wish it to be in 3 decimal places. Can anyome please help me. thank you.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? SQL Server? MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do an inner query in SELECT clause

```
select p1.person, count(p1.person), count(p1.person) / (SELECT COUNT(p2.person) FROM person_table p2)
from person_table p1
group by p1.person
```

Edit: if you want only up to 3 decimal:

```
select 
  p1.person, 
  count(p1.person), 
  ROUND(count(p1.person) / (SELECT COUNT(p2.person) FROM person_table p2), 3)
from person_table p1
group by p1.person
```

Edit 2: OP edited his/her table

```
select 
  new_table.person, 
  count(new_table.person),
  ROUND(
    count(new_table.person) / 
    SELECT COUNT(new_table_COUNTER.person) FROM (
      person_table_1
      inner join person_table_2
      on person_table_1.user_name = person_table_2.user_all_name
    ) new_table_COUNTER )
from 
  (
  person_table_1
  inner join person_table_2
  on person_table_1.user_name = person_table_2.user_all_name
  ) new_table
group by new_table.person
```

Comment: Im so sorry sir, I edited my question before you answer. Yes, I try that way but i cant do it with my edited question. Sorry again.

Comment: @Anony even if your table changed, you just need to nest it inside the SELECT clause as before

Comment: thank you but somehow all show 0 even when I used your round method.

Comment: What about without round method? What RDBMS software do you use? Is it MySQL, Postre, SQL server or other?

Comment: I used aginity pro. I do not know which is it? I am new to sql. Can you tell me which this software belongs to>

Comment: I marked it as answer and I managed to convert it to decimal however, can I know aginity pro falls under which category from the above mentioned? Please

Comment: After a quick google search, it seems like Aginity Pro is just a database management tool. It can handle: (copy pasted from its official website): amazon redshift
amazon rds, 
amazon aurora, 
snowflake, 
apache hive,
microsoft sql server, 
azure sql server, 
pivotal greenplum, 
apache spark, 
azure data warehouse, 
pure data for analytics, 
ibm db2, 
postgresql

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
declare @tbl table ([person] varchar(5));
insert into @tbl values 
('a'),('a'),('a'),('b'),('b'),('c');
-- here we tabke max(rowsCnt), but we wwant any value, because every value is the same in that column
select person, count(*) * 1.0 / max(rowsCnt) [percentage] from (
    select person,
           count(*) over (partition by (select null)) rowsCnt
    from @tbl
) a group by person
```